using gio move in a script executed in a cron job in Ubuntu
I have a program which starts a bash shell script that uses "gio move". When the program is run from the command line everything works fine. When the program is started from a cron job it fails to execute the "gio move" statement, but it does everything else in the cron job.
I included definitions of all of my env variables in the script thinking that some variable must be needed (in included every thing printed with "env").
There is obviously some else needed.
The command file I'm running does two move commands from the local disk to my google drive.

All operations like Google Drive access work by talking to a dbus service.
Instead of a cron job use a systemd timer running as your user. This way it can access your session.
